# Error in UIImageView Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Absolute Swift beginner here.

I have been trying to get a simple set of png's to animate.

Here is what I have:

[image: I tried to post a screenshot of the errors, but I need at least 10 reputation to post - sorry.]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var myImageView : UIImageView
@IBOutlet var animationBtn : UIButton
var imageList = UIImage[]()

@IBAction func animationBtnClicked(sender : AnyObject) {
    startAnimation()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    for i in 1...13
    {
        let imageName = "\(i)"
        imageList += UIImage(named: imageName)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func startAnimation() -> Void
{
    if !myImageView.isAnimating()
    {
        myImageView.animationImages = imageList
        myImageView.startAnimating()
        animationBtn.setTitle("Stop Animation", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else
    {
        myImageView.stopAnimating()
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"bomb.jpg")
        animationBtn.setTitle("Start Animation", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

}

Here is the adjusted code if it helps anyone. 
Cheers

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var animationBtn: UIButton!
var imageList = [UIImage]()


@IBAction func animationBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    startAnimation()
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    for i in 1...99

    {
        let imageName = "\(i)"
        imageList.append(UIImage(named: imageName)!)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
        func startAnimation() -> Void

        {
            myImageView.animationImages = imageList
            myImageView.startAnimating()

}
```

}

Comment: Can you share a link to your screenshot ? Or can you paste the error message here ?

Comment: Thanks Midhun, here is the link to the error pic  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=10zpe7l&s=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those errors messages shows the exact issue.

#### Issue 1

For fixing `has no initializers`, you need implement at-least one init function in your class.

#### Issue 2

For fixing `IBOutlet has non-optional`, you need to change your `IBOutlet` variables to optionals.

```
@IBOutlet var myImageView : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var animationBtn : UIButton!
```

#### Issue 3

For fixing that `[UIImage] is not identical to UInt8`. The `+=` can't be used to append a single `UIImage` to `[UIImage]`

You need to change:

```
imageList += UIImage(named: imageName)
```

to

```
imageList.append(UIImage(named: imageName))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly Midhun. I can't upvote it, as I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks very much